# metal - superconductor surface effect

Tags: superconductivity

What happens when You make a contact junction between normal metal with some fermi energy $E_{F}$ and superconductor with fermi level $E_{SC}$, but this levels are not necessarily the same ?

There is some analogy between p-n junction or contact potential in metals?